# In a while loop changeing "<" to "<= " in the same code draws a different turtle graphic

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Question about using while loops.

I notice that if I use a "<" condition in a while loop it will draw a different picture than if I use a "<=" condition for the same code.

Below you will see two different code sets and the associated pictures the render for reference.

Any help or feed back is appreciated!

For the given code I use a while loop to start to draw a circle from squares:

```
import turtle

def draw_square(some_turtle):
count =0
while count <4 : 
    some_turtle.forward(100)
    some_turtle.right(90)
    count += 1

def draw_circle(): 
    win = turtle.Screen()
    win.bgcolor("red")
    nic = turtle.Turtle()
    nic.shape("turtle")
    nic.color("blue")
    nic.speed(2)
    count = 0
    while count <4:
    draw_square(nic)
    nic.right(10)
    count += 1 
    win.exitonclick()

draw_circle()
draw_square("1")
```

It renders the following image:

[turtle drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UV0JS.png)

I then change the < to <= as such:

import turtle

```
def draw_square(some_turtle):
count =0
while count <=4 : 
    some_turtle.forward(100)
    some_turtle.right(90)
    count += 1

def draw_circle(): 
    win = turtle.Screen()
    win.bgcolor("red")
    nic = turtle.Turtle()
    nic.shape("turtle")
    nic.color("blue")
    nic.speed(2)
    count = 0
    while count <=4:
    draw_square(nic)
    nic.right(10)
    count += 1 
    win.exitonclick()

draw_circle()
draw_square("1")
```

and the following is rendered:

[turtle drawing 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqYW5.png)

Why does changing the <= to < in the while loop have such an impact on the drawing?

Comment: Because you've changed the condition in both square and circle so the pointer (turtle) ends up a different point on the square for the next loop. Don't change the condition for the square drawing.

Comment: Thanks @AChampion. Given that it's <= shouldn't it be the last loop and not the first that would've been different?

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the position of the turtle after the square has been drawn. The difference is in the draw_square function.

For the first example:

```
while count <4 : 
    some_turtle.forward(100)
    some_turtle.right(90)
    count += 1
```

The turtle stops in the upper left hand corner of the square like so:

[Turtle Answer1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQ5Hg.jpg)

If the second example where we change "<" to "<=" the turtle stops in the upper right hand corner because it's including the forth loop as such:

[Turtle_Answer2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZ6mP.jpg)

This in-turn changes the point in which the turtle pivots to make the next square fundamentally changing the picture as a whole.